# Dynamic Array of Structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'm trying to create an array of structures, but I'm not sure how to proceed with declaring an array and mallocing it. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 128

typedef char String[MAX_STRING]

typedef struct {
  String Name; //Name of the person                                             
  String Best; //Name of the best friend                                        
} Names;

int main(void) {

}
```

This is an exercise I'm trying to do and the end product should be like this: [HERE](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~wuchtys/CSC322-14S/Assessment/LT9.html)

Comment: Please read up on dynamic allocation and pointers. ome back when you have something that nearly works. Tip: Also use dynamic allocation for your strings.

Comment: Please don't use fixed array sizes like this (`MAX_STRING`). You won't be able to count to three before a use case comes along that breaks your artificial limit, leading to horrible, nasty, and completely pointless bugs. For the rest, do as Deduplicator suggests.

Comment: I'll try. I saw some different examples and got confused. I just wanted a point of start so I can finish my program. But I'll try to read some more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

typedef struct
{
    char* Name; //Why complicate things using a string?
    char* Best;
}Names;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    //Create an array of pointers. 
    //Each element of the array is a pointer to a struct "Names"
    Names** data = malloc(N*sizeof(Names*));
    //data[i] is a array element which points to a single struct "Names".
    //Dynamically allocate memory for each struct
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        data[i] = malloc(sizeof(Names));
    }
    //Rest is your assignment
    data[0]->Name = "aaaa";
    data[0]->Best = "bbbb";
    data[1]->Name = "cccc";
    data[1]->Best = "dddd";
    data[2]->Name = "eeee";
    data[2]->Best = "ffff";
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\n",data[i]->Name,data[i]->Best);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_STRING 128
#define NUMBER_OF_STRUCTURES_IN_ARRAY 10

typedef char String[MAX_STRING]

typedef struct {
  String Name; //Name of the person                                             
  String Best; //Name of the best friend                                        
} Names;

int main(void) 
    {
    int rCode=0;
    Names *names_A = NULL;
    int    index;

    names_A = malloc(sizeof(*names_A) * NUMBER_OF_STRUCTURES_IN_ARRAY);
    if(NULL == names)
        {
        rCode=ENOMEM;
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc() failed\n");
        goto CLEANUP;
        }

     for(index=0; index < NUMBER_OF_STRUCTURES_IN_ARRAY; ++index)
         {
         strcpy(names_A[index].Name, "Some Name");
         strcpy(names_A[index].Best, "Another Name");
         }

CLEANUP:

if(names_A)
   free(names_A);

return(rCode);
}
```